# TSQL Month and Year to Date Conversion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that stores an `int` for month and year. I need to convert that to a date (we can use the first day of the month and the `day`).

I tried something like below but got an error about converting `int` to `date`

```
AND CAST(ym.year + '-' + ym.month + '-' + '01' AS DATE) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

End result should be be something like  `2016-05-01` so I can check the date against a start and end date that I pass to the function.

Comment: Google "tsql convert date from int"

Comment: This is why you should not store date information like this. You should store this as a date or datetime datatype.

Comment: the use case was to allow a user to pick the desired month they need their criteria reviewed. While we allow a user to set a specific date, it allows allows a "fuzzy date" in which they can provide a rough guess. I just needed a date to go off of in my query, doesn't need to be accurate aside from the month/year.

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, modified for your use:

```
declare @YY int = 2016
declare @MM int = 5
select CAST(CAST(@YY as varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@MM as varchar(2)),2) + '-01' as DATE)
```

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2012 on you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh213228%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

```
AND DATEFROMPARTS(ym.year, ym.month, 1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AND DateFromParts(ym.year, ym.month, 1) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

EDIT: For old versions of SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(ym.year*10000+ym.month*100+1 AS CHAR(8)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you are on 2008 or lower

```
select cast(
            cast(ym.year as varchar(4))+
            case when len(ym.month) < 2 then '0' + cast(ym.month as varchar(2)) else cast(ym.month as varchar(2)) end +
            '01' as date)
```

The Error you are getting is because when you `CONCAT` your `INT` values there is no leading 0 for days before 10, or months before October, thus your `CAST` to `DATE` is essentially missing values to do the conversion. Here we are padding based off the length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CAST(CAST(ym.year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(ym.month AS varchar) + '-01'  AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go the data way and create a table of year, month and date as first of month then join the tables. this may be faster for a large table especially if the number of years and months in the original table is limited.

So if you have a years data in your original table there would only be 12 records required, which as a join added into your processing should be quick.

To avoid missing dates, build the lookup table from original data:

```
SELECT year, month, cast(cast(year*10000+month*100+1 as char(8)) as date) as FirstOfMonth 
INTO #FirstOfMonth FROM mytable GROUP BY year, month
```